# How would I make the Windows Python Launcher recognize Cygwin Python 2 & 3?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I have CygWin with both Python 2 & 3 installed.  When I run `py` I get;

```
> py
launcher build: 32bit
launcher executable: Console
File 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\py.ini' non-existent
File 'C:\WINDOWS\py.ini' non-existent
Called with command line:
locating Pythons in 64bit registry
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath: The system cannot find the file specified.
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.4\InstallPath: The system cannot find the file specified.
locating Pythons in native registry
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath: The system cannot find the file specified.
locate_pythons_for_key: unable to open PythonCore key in HKLM
found no configured value for 'python'
search for default Python found no interpreter
Can't find a default Python.
```

If I created a `py.ini`, what would I put in it?  [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) is kind of vague on that point.

Also, the Windows Python Launcher doesn't seem to respond properly to `py -h` or `py --help`.  Is there a description of the command line arguments for it?

I can run CygWin `python` and `python3` from a Powershell prompt, so paths seem right.

```
PS C:\Users\user> which python
/usr/bin/python
PS C:\Users\user> which python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8
```

Other ideas?  Perhaps I could install a CygWin `py` that would supercede Windows' and behave sanely?

Comment: Cygwin python packages do NOT write on Windows register. Moreover the current Python 3 package is version 3.6.9. Are you sure that you are running the Cygwin phyton's ?

Comment: @matzeri, I think the registry shows old installations long removed.  I updated my post to show I am running cygwin's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Win 10 create "C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Local\py.ini" with e.g.

```
[commands]
cygpy2=C:\cygwin64\bin\python2.7.exe
```

Create a test file, e.g. "test_cygpy2" in current directory with

```
#! cygpy2
import sys
print 'Hello, python', sys.version
```

and run it as

```
> py test_cygpy2.py
```

I tried using the -i option. This works:

```
> py -i test_cygpy2.py
Hello, python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 20 2019, 12:15:19)
[GCC 7.4.0]
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.16 (default, Mar 20 2019, 12:15:19) \n[GCC 7.4.0]'
>>>
```